# Cannot GET on POST request

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I have an API that takes in 3 url parameters and writes into a mongodb collection.  My understanding is that it should be post request since it's sending data to my back end, but when sending the data in, I get a Cannot Get... error.

routes.js

```
// JavaScript source code
var friends = require('./../controllers/friends.js');

module.exports = function(app)
{
    app.post('/friends/new/:fname/:lname/:bday', function (request, response)
    {
        friends.create(request, response);
    })
}
```

Controller:

```
// JavaScript source code
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Friend = mongoose.model('Friend');

module.exports = 
{
    create: function(request, response)
    {
        var friendInstance = new Friend();
        friendInstance.first_name = request.params.fname;
        friendInstance.last_name = request.params.lname;
        friendInstance.b_day = request.params.bday;
        friendInstance.save(function(err)
        {
            if (err)
            {
                response.josn(err);
            }
}
```

URL:

```
http://localhost:8000/friends/new/Gelo/Maverick/9999-9-99
```

Error:

```
Cannot GET /friends/new/Gelo/Maverick/9999-9-99
```

Comment: And where is the code in which you make the request?

Comment: did you check the developer tools network tab to confirm the request is a `POST` rather than a `GET` - oops, this is node.js - you haven't shown what the client does

Comment: If you're sending the data as URL parameters then the request does not need to be a `POST`.

Comment: I don't have a client.  I was entering passing my parameters through the url.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're seeing that error because you must be trying to access the url via the web browser, which sends the GET request. You should use an app like [Postman](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/postman/fhbjgbiflinjbdggehcddcbncdddomop?hl=en) to make POST requests instead.